# Create Interactsh integration in Python

Tags: python, server, integration

I want create an app which connect my interactsh-server (*self-host*) in Python.

I don't find anything about that.

https://github.com/projectdiscovery/interactsh?tab=readme-ov-file#interactsh-server

> I want to create a app, I need create a server-side that when I use the client-side creates a subdomain on the server (wildcard - `subdomainexample.testoob.com`) to test payload ([UUID].testoob.com) and when someone sends a request for this payload, I in my tool (client-side) receive the interaction

Example for server-side:

- Create a subdomain when a user uses the tool
- Use websocket to constantly connect to the client-side on url interactions (URL to create connection: testoob.com)

Examples for the client-side:

- When I start the tool, it asks the server to create a payload (example payload: kdwoi4r3.testoob.com)
- Create a connection with the server-side (testoob.com)
- When the server-side detects that it has received an http request, it sends it to the tool (client-side) via the socket

My domain is on Cloudflare, I need to configure it to create subdomains automatically.

In a nutshell: I want to create an interactsh integration in Python to use in my script